# Node.js first-error

Tags: node.js

If I do:

```
const debug = require('debug')('app');
var err = new Error("my error");
debug(err);
err.message = "new error";
debug(err);
```

I do not see the new error message. But if I do:

```
debug(err.message);
```

I do see the new error message. My question is what is the 'err' really? Its `typeof` is `object` but why don't I see all of the objects parts?

Answer (score 0):

When the `debug` library encounters an error, it logs `error.stack`, which is a pre-computed string that has the error message baked in. That's why changing the error message after the creation of the error does not appear to show up in your code, because the `error.stack` property has been set.

You can see that behavior on [these lines](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/master/debug.js#L194-L197):

```
if (val instanceof Error) return val.stack || val.message;
```

Either way you should not modify error messages after the error has been created.